# Drag and Drop allow only one object per target

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm sure this is simple but I have the drag and drop code that works wonderfully...however, it allows me to drop muliple objects per target. What I want is to allow only one object per target and I've looked and can't seem to find how to test to see if an object had already been dropt. Here's the code I have:

```
package com {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import com.greensock.*;

public class DraggableObject extends MovieClip 
{
    protected var origPos:Point;
    public function DraggableObject() 
    {
        origPos = new Point(x, y);
        buttonMode = true; // changes cursor to hand
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);

    }


    protected function down (event:MouseEvent): void
    {
        parent.addChild(this); // adds object to the top of the display list to keep the object on top
        startDrag(); // built in Flash method
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp);
        var upPosX = x + 5;
        var upPosY = y - 5;
        TweenMax.to(this, .2, {dropShadowFilter:{color:0x666666, alpha:1, blurX:12, blurY:12, distance:12}});
        TweenLite.to(this, .2, {x: upPosX, y: upPosY});
        mouseEnabled = false;
    }

    protected function stageUp (event:MouseEvent): void 
    {
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageUp); // good coding
        stopDrag(); // built in Flash method
        TweenMax.to(this, .5, {dropShadowFilter:{color:0x666666, alpha:0, blurX:12, blurY:12, distance:12}});

         if (dropTarget.parent.name == "root1"){
                returnToOrigPos();
        } 
            else if(dropTarget)// dropTarget is a built in property this means if dropTarget != null
        {
            trace("dropt on "+dropTarget.parent.name);
            x = dropTarget.parent.x;
            y = dropTarget.parent.y;

            //buttonMode = false; //only use these to keep the user's selection...can't change if these are active.
            //removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, down);

        } 
        mouseEnabled = true;
    }

    protected function returnToOrigPos(): void 
    {
            x = origPos.x;
            y = origPos.y;
    }
}
```

I was thinking that `hitTestObject` or `dropTarget` would work but can't figure out how to use them.

Thanks for any help!
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property (eg: _hasDroppedObject) to whatever kind of object you're dropping objects into and set it to true when an object is dropped into it:

```
dropTarget.hasDroppedObject = true;
```

Then change your "if (dropTarget.parent.name == "root1")" line to:

```
if (dropTarget.parent.name == "root1" || dropTarget.hasDroppedObject) {
```

(This assumes you have access to the drop-receiving Class).

Comment: Thanks @moosefetcher, I looked into adding a property but it is beyond my coding skills. I've not created a drop target class and adding a property is beyond my understanding.